# Django: uploaded file not available in request.FILES unless you call request.body first

Tags: django, file, upload

I used `fileupload` jquery script to upload a small simple file. On the Django server side, I received the POST, but `request.FILES` is empty.
However, if I call `request.body` before calling any other request's APIs/macros, the uploaded file info then appears in `request.FILES`.

Is this the kind of quantum theory in HTTP? Can anyone kindly explain it? What is the proper way to handle the uploaded file?

The problem is not unique to file upload. It happened to all ajax posts. I suspect that some sort of settings may be required in order to have the underlying system automatically process incoming stream and construct objects out of it.

Here is server side code segment:

```
class FileUploadView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)

        # temporary solution in order to trigger the underlying system to
        # construct objects from incoming stream.
        bb = request.body

        field_name = 'data_file'
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            filename = form.files[field_name].name
            if FileDataSource.allowed_file_type(filename):
                self.save_file(filename,
                               request.FILES[field_name], 
                               UPLOAD_FOLDER)
                self.register_datasource(filename, UPLOAD_FOLDER)
                return self.reply_features(filename=filename)
            else:
                pass
```

and here is client side jquery:

```
$("#fileupload").fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(data) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show more `def post()` code and your jquery fileupload library source (or library name)

Comment: Thanks, here is code segment: